# Are multiple Bluetooth adapters under Android possible?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Are multiple Bluetooth adapters under Android possible (e.g in order to be able to connect to more than 7 devices through these adapters)? Android API does not even mention the possibility of accessing more than one adapter: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter()

I have no restrictions on root or running native code.

Comment: I don't think it's a restriction on the code. It's a restriction on the hardware.

Comment: @DeeV what do you mean? I think I would be able to connect any number of adapters via USB OTG.

Answer (score 2):

Even it's not possible with Android API, if Android device has OTG then USB BT dongle can be attached to that device (at least is possible connect to Android several BT SPP devices).

Comment: Did you try the bluez stack (https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez/+/b4fbbb033ec3165d153b626c48e560c021fe59a7/android/README)? I think it would be possible with that.